# How do I tell QGIS to stop fetching tiles?

Tags: qgis

I've added an vector tile server to a project in QGIS. Sometimes the server starts timing out and if I look in the network logger, there are hundreds of failed requests piling up, even after I've toggled the layer off on the map. Is there a way to tell QGIS to pause rendering and stop fetching tiles, like a kill switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the timeout for network requests (only for all requests, so not for an individual source) and also change how many time QGIS tries to request a tile.

Change these in `Settings -> Options -> Network`.

Again, this will change the settings for all requests/tile requests so it can affect other aspects of your work.

[image]

[image]